# How to select all values in an Excel data table column?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I have an Excel data table (not just a plain worksheet) and I want **select** all **data** (not the header and not the rows below the data table) in a **column**. What's the easiest way to do this? I use mouse at the moment but it gets inconvenient when the table has many rows.

Comment: Does the table data start at row 2?

Comment: Not necessarily but let's say it does if it makes things easier..

Comment: Well if if did, you could select the last cell, hit `Shift` + `Page Up`, then `Shift` + `Down Arrow` to remove the header.

Comment: How do you select the last cell if the table can be very large? It would then be a good suggestion.

Comment: @Gerasimos.Zap That's the answer! Please put it as such and I'll mark it. Thanks!

Comment: Or `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `Down/Up`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Borek another easiest way is by using keyboard shortcut `ctrl` + `space`. It will select the whole column.

Comment: This is fantastic! Didn't expect such a simple and easy-to-press shortcut.

Comment: For completeness' sake, the same can be achieved by right-clicking, Select, Table Column Data.

Answer (score 2):

When you hover over the top border of the header cell, the cursor turns to a down arrow.  (Same as when you hover over the column letter.)  Click once and it selects the content of the table column.  Click a second time and it adds the header cell.

Roy

Comment: This selects the whole column for me, including the header (row 1) and the empty lines below the table.